# How generate bunch of string resource in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, string, android-studio, android-resources

I have a kind of content management file in my Android file, where I have around 100 of string to map to my UI. I need to extract all those strings into resources files (like strings.xml).

I'm currently writing all those resources Ids in my java file : like R.string.myStringId1 .... until myStringId100.

Now I need to create my XML file with those 100 string references and content.
Android Studio offer a way to generate missing string resource automatically, one by one.

Is there any way to tell or script Android studio, generate all missing resource ID to the strings.xml file ? and not doing 100 time Alt+1 => Ok => Ok

Comment: there are many programms to simulate key presses :3

Comment: Maybe the android studio macros could help.

Comment: ok, but I need to loop over all resources references in the file that are not available in the projet. This I do not see how macro either key presses simulation will help me, is it ?